# Why do arrow keys mess up stdout?

Tags: c, multithreading, bash, terminal, network-programming

I am writing a simple client - server programs in C for practicing network programming. The server can handle multiple clients by using multi threading. Each client is serviced in a separate thread. The client uses two threads : one to take user input from stdin and one to print to stdout.

I tested the program with regular text and it works perfectly. However, it behaves very weirdly when I input arrow keys (left key = ^[[D, right key = ^[[C, up key = ^[[A, down key = ^[[B).

For example see this output:
This is the input I sent in sequentially (in client):

```
>> test
I got your message
>> test1
I got your message
>> test2
I got your message
>> test3
I got your message
```

This is the (correct) output in server:

```
Here is the message: test
Here is the message: test1
Here is the message: test2
Here is the message: test3
```

Now I input random arrow keys (after inputting test3):

```
>>^[[D^[[A^[[C^[[A^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[D^[[B^[[C^[[D^[[B^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[D^[[A^[[D^[[C^[[A
I got your message
```

However, server prints nothing (I assumed the characters were escaped):

```
Here is the message: test
Here is the message: test1
Here is the message: test2
Here is the message: test3
Here is the message: 

Now, I start inputting normal text:

>> test4
I got your message
>> test5
I got your message
>> test6
I got your message
>> test7
I got your message
>> test8
I got your message
>> test9
I got your message
>> test10
I got your message
```

When I check the server's stdout, all the previous printout is overwritten:

```
Here is the message: test4
Here is the message: test5
Here is the message: test6
Here is the message: test7
Here is the message: test8
Here is the message: test9
Here is the message: test10
```

Most importantly, the behavior changes with the random keystrokes of arrows I enter. Sometimes, the input won't override the server's stdout but it inserts the input within stdout.

I am not sure why this is happening but, if anyone wants to see my source, I can post it. The source is not long - the client and server are about 100 lines long.

---

Ok I tested each key seperately.

The down key and up key seem to move the file pointer in stdout by lines. And left and right keys seem to do nothing.

Comment: What did you expect the arrow keys to do?

Comment: Try to use a debugger and step through the code, line by line, when you read the  cursor-key input, and see what you do when you send it to the server. Then do the same in the server, to see if it receives anything at all, and step through the code in how it handles the data.

Comment: I thought it would just print those characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `stdout` (which is a stream of bytes) with the result of feeding those bytes into a terminal emulator. If you capture your server's 
`stdout` into a file, you'll be able to look at it using a hex editor (or the `hd` command, and you'll see the actual bytes sent.

The terminal emulator takes these bytes and converts them into actions which result in your display showing you something. Bytes or sequences of bytes may be displayed as single graphemes (visible symbols) or interpreted as control codes (move the cursor, change output or background colour, etc.), or even just ignored.

To understand how these bytes are interpreted, you could consult the documentation for your terminal emulator (if you can find it) or try the useful summaries in the [XTerm documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) (which is specific to `xterm` but most modern terminal emulators are similar) or [`man 4 console_codes`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) (which is specific to the Linux console, but again similar to most terminal emulators).

Comment: Is there any way I can instruct Bash (which I am using) to treat everything as a character. Basically, I am storing what i read from the client in a char array buffer. Is there a function that prints the characters exactly (I am using printf currently)?

Comment: @1729. Bash is just another program. It is *not* a terminal emulator. (I don't know what terminal emulator you are using: it is the program you use to create the window inside of which bash is running. If you didn't have a terminal emulator, you wouldn't have a window :-) ) So bash does treat everything as a character, but the terminal emulator interprets the characters as it sees fit. If you want to see the actual bytes, use `hd` (either pipe the program into `hd` or save the output into a file and then use `hd` on the file).

Comment: @1729: you can also try `od` but I find `hd` easier. What distribution/OS are you using?

Comment: `od` seems to work. So, do I call od from my c program when I want to print the buffer? Btw, I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: @1729: `hd` should be in the `util-linux` package; I'm surprised you don't have it. It should be a symlink to the `hexdump` utility. Personally, I wouldn't call an external utility. Instead, you should think about what you want to display, exactly, and write a little code to display what you want. Or just dump the data to stdout, and (as I suggested earlier) capture the log to a file or pipe it through `hd`.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow keys are sending multi-character ANSI escape sequences.  BASH (and other programs) use a library like readline (or maybe curses) to convert the escape sequences into cursor movement/editing.  If you do not want to use such libraries, you would have place the terminal into raw mode and read and process each escape sequence and move the cursor by sending cursor movement sequences, a difficult process.

Comment: Can I use some C function that prints the bytes exactly instead of messing with the terminal emulators?